# What is the correct way to represent dates in a graph database (ArangoDB)?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, arangodb

Are there any pitfalls in representing dates as nodes (in a separate collection) in a graph database, as opposed to properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would say that you would represent the date as a property on a vertex or an edge.  I am not sure I have seen one represented as a node before.

The real question between node vs. property comes down to what are you going to be using the dates for?

If you are going to be using them to traverse through within your graph (e.g. From an order find me all other orders that were placed on the same date) then I would make them a node.  If you are going to be using them to filter a traversal (e.g. Find me all orders on X date or Find me all orders between X and Y) then make it a property.

Comment: Not sure I understand this answer. A Neo4j node is synonymous with *vertex*. And nodes have properties. What do you mean by "node vs property?" Relationship (*edges*) may also have properties. Maybe you're talking about a date represented by its own node (which would still require a property to store the date value), vs a date property of some other type of node?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I was not clear.  I was referring to a Vertex which had a label of "date" which has a property containing the date versus putting a property of date on a different vertex

Comment: From experience, the best way to store dates in ArangoDB is to convert them to UnixEpochTime (in milliseconds if required) and store them as properties either against vertices or edges. That way you can perform the classic date queries like before, after, between, outside, etc. because they are stored as numbers.

Comment: Thank you all, your answers show that my question was concrete enough. Although I am not 100% convinced I'll proceed with dates being properties. The discussion of whether something should be a property or a vertex in graph database is wide. If someone has links to such discussions, please post them.

Comment: Use this as a way of helping you answer your question. If you weren't using a graph database, how would you store the dates? In your use case, would you solve your problem by creating a row for each date, using a many-to-many table to associate dates to data, or would you add a date column to a row, and use that technique to associate dates with your data.

This is an important data modelling question with graph databases. Rows in an RDBMS or NOSQL database are like vertices. Many-to-many tables are like edges.

Hope that helps you answer your question.